# Which flag will North and South Korea march under at the Olympic games?

Tags: international-relations, north-korea, south-korea

I read through a [BBC article](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-asia-42972216) which stated that Kim Jong Un's sister is likely to attend the opening ceremony of this years Olympic games in Pyeongchang. The was one thing that got me confused though:

> Both Koreas will march under one flag at the opening ceremony.

Knowing about the relationship between both countries, it seems pretty much unacceptable for both sides to *march* under the flag of the respective other.

*Was it already publicly announced which flag this is going to be, and, if yes, how does it look like?*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is not much more to say than refer to you this wiki page about the [Korean Unification Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Unification_Flag), which also happens to be the first page you would find when googling "flag korea olympic games".

The flag represents the Korean peninsula in blue on a white background. You can see it held by athletes from both Koreas in Turin 2006 Winter Olympics games on a photo in this [article](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/01/17/world/asia/north-south-korea-olympics.html) that confirms it will be used in 2018 as well.

Edit: As pointed in a comment by Shantanu Hebbar, the version of the Korean Unification Flag that will be used is the one without a dot for the contested [Dokdo Islands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liancourt_Rocks) (aka Takeshima, aka Liancourt) after a [protest](http://www.straitstimes.com/asia/east-asia/japan-protests-unified-korea-olympic-flag-featuring-disputed-islands) by Japanese Prime Minister Shinzo Abe. According to Wikipedia (without a source for this claim), Ulleungdo Island will not figure either, so it should be [this version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korean_Unification_Flag#/media/File:Unification_flag_of_Korea_%28pre_2006%29.svg) of the flag.

Comment: Actually, the flag will be changed. Japan has expressed its reservation on the Korea's  using a flag that shows the Dokdo islands which is disputed. http://www.straitstimes.com/asia/east-asia/japan-protests-unified-korea-olympic-flag-featuring-disputed-islands will be helpful.